# Pretty URLs and folder path gone away

Tags: angularjs

I have a project uploaded inside a subfolder, html5 mode enabled, and when I navigate to www.mysite.com/subfolder I get a redirection to www.mysite.com

What is causing that and how do I keep the subfolder path? Notice that doesn't matter if I put the subfolder path in the URL path, I'll get the redirect everytime (keep in mind that even I'm getting a redirect, the project works).

```
(function() {
  var routes;
  routes = function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'aa/main.html',
      resolve: {}
    }).when('/shop', {
      templateUrl: 'aa/shop.html',
      resolve: {}
    }).when('/items/:itemId*', {
      templateUrl: function(urlattr) {
        return 'aa/items/' + urlattr.itemId + '.html';
      },
      resolve: {}
    }).when('/cart', {
      templateUrl: 'aa/cart.html',
      resolve: {}
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  };
  routes.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
  angular.module('myApp').config(routes);
})();
```

Comment: Check your `<base>` tag. It will need to be set to `<base href="https://example.com/subfolder/">`

Comment: Damn lol completely forgot about it, thank you!

Comment: Uhm.. why do I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: start_counter is not defined onload @ shop:81` when refreshing the page on /shop?

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730654/angularjs-pretty-url-not-working-on-page-refresh-if-base-href-is-set-to-other-th) the reason?